# How does a method know where it get called?

Tags: groovy, closures

I don't know how to describe my question in words, so I try it with code :)

Gebish, an selenium implementation for Groovy, does this:

```
$("#myForm").with {
    $("input").value("abc")
}
```

This looks pretty much like jQuery and it almost does the same things.
In this example I set the value of every input *inside* in the given form to "abc". But how does Groovy know in which form I am? Or in other words, how does the `$` method with *input* knows where it's called and to who it has a relationship?

I know that in that `.with { ... }` is a `it` variable and that `$("input")` is "looking" at it. How would it look like if I create my own method like `$` that is able to look that that *it* without to telling the method that there is that *it*? Because it is `$("input").value("abc")` and not something like `$("input", it).value("abc")`

I would research it by myself, but sadly I don't even know how to call what I explained.

I guess it would work with looking at the stack trace, but I know that it would be the worst thing to do :D

Answer (score 2):

When you use `with` any method invoked or properties accessed inside the closure are resolved against the object that `with` is called on. Here's a very simple example:

```
'12345'.with {
  // prints 5, because the string that "with" is called on has 5 characters
  println size()  
}
```

So the code above is functionally identical to

```
println '12345'.size()
```

So hopefully the answer to your question should now be obvious

> how does Groovy know in which form I am?

Because this

```
$("#myForm").with {
    $("input").value("abc")
}
```

is effectively:

```
$("#myForm").$("input").value("abc")
```